# INNER JOIN Multiple tables - access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery

I'm here because I'm stack on a query.

I have a table like this, called t :

```
Order_ID
Product_ID  
Quantity
Discount
Revenue
Cost
Year
Supplier_ID
Customer_ID
Employee_ID
```

From this query I want to obtain something like :

```
Product_ID
Quantities_ordered_2013
Tot_Revenue_2013
Quantities_ordered_2014
Tot_Revenue_2014
Quantities_ordered_2015
Tot_Revenue_2015
```

I created 3 sub-queries to group by product information for every year like this :

```
   SELECT t.FK_Product_ID, Count(t.FK_Order_ID) AS Orders_2013, Sum(t.Revenue) AS Revenue_2013
FROM t
WHERE (((t.Year)=2013))
GROUP BY t.FK_Product_ID AS 2013_Product
```

Once I create the 3 tables, how do I merge them together to obtain my table?

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: Explain "merge". Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation where you move `WHERE` conditions into [`IIF()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) expressions to be aggregated on with `COUNT` and `SUM`. No joining needed. Also, use table aliases to avoid repeating long table names (which ideally does not start with numbers or special characters).

```sql
SELECT t.FK_Product_ID AS Product 
       , SUM(IIF(t.[Year]=2013, 1, 0) AS Orders_2013
       , SUM(IIF(t.[Year]=2013, Revenue, 0) AS Revenue_2013
       , SUM(IIF(t.[Year]=2014, 1, 0) AS Orders_2014
       , SUM(IIF(t.[Year]=2014, Revenue, 0) AS Revenue_2014
       , SUM(IIF(t.[Year]=2015, 1, 0) AS Orders_2015
       , SUM(IIF(t.[Year]=2015, Revenue, 0) AS Revenue_2015
FROM 12_A1_Q3_01_Denormalized t
GROUP BY t.FK_Product_ID
```

---

Alternatively, MS Access maintains the unique [cross tab query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8). However, since this special query pivots one aggregation at a time, you would need multiple underlying queries to be joined at end:

```sql
TRANSFORM COUNT(*) AS Orders
SELECT t.FK_Product_ID AS Product 
FROM 12_A1_Q3_01_Denormalized t
GROUP BY t.FK_Product_ID 
PIVOT t.[Year] IN ([2013], [2014], [2015])
```

```sql
TRANSFORM SUM(t.[Revenue]) AS Revenue
SELECT t.FK_Product_ID AS Product 
FROM 12_A1_Q3_01_Denormalized t
GROUP BY t.FK_Product_ID 
PIVOT t.[Year] IN ([2013], [2014], [2015])
```

```sql
SELECT t.FK_Product_ID AS Product
       , o.[2013] AS Orders_2013
       , r.[2013] AS Revenue_2013 
       , o.[2014] AS Orders_2014
       , r.[2014] AS Revenue_2014 
       , o.[2015] AS Orders_2015
       , r.[2015] AS Revenue_2015 

FROM OrdersCrossTabQuery o
INNER JOIN RevenueCrossTabQuery r
   ON o.[Product] = r.[Product]
```

Comment: Great! I feel as if I learned something new! Thanks!